# A corollary of Pole assignment theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, control-theory

The well-known *Pole Assignment Theorem* is

> **Pole Assignment Theorem.** Given $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n},B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, for any target pole set $P=\{\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n\}$ which is closed under complex conjugate, there exists a matrix $F\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ such that $\lambda(A+BF)=P$ if and only if $(A,B)$ is controllable.

If $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $\mu$ is still an eigenvalue of $A+BF$ for any $F\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $\mu$ is called an uncontrollable pole of $A$, my question is

> **Question.** The pole assignment problem has a solution i.e. given a target pole set $P$, there exists a matrix $F\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ such that $$\lambda(A+BF)=P$$
>    if and only if all uncontrollable poles of $A$ are in the target pole set $P$.

by real Schur decomposition, we can choose an orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that $$Q^TAQ=\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12} \\
0 & A_{22}
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $\lambda(A_{11})$ consists of all the uncontrollable poles of $A$.
Let
$$Q^TB=\begin{bmatrix}
B_1 \\B_2
\end{bmatrix}$$
but I do not have idea that how to continue... any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is closely related to the [Kalman decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_decomposition), from which it can be noted that $\lambda(A_{22})$ instead of $\lambda(A_{11})$ should contain all uncontrollable poles of $A$. You want to show that the eigenvalues of $A + B\,F$ and thus also $Q^\top(A + B\,F)\,Q$ always contain the uncontrollable poles of $A$. Using this what can you say about $B_1$ and $B_2$? Hint: use $F\,Q = \begin{bmatrix}F_1 & F_2\end{bmatrix}$ and look at the eigenvalues of $Q^\top(A + B\,F)\,Q$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it! The key is Kalman decomposition...